# CSS Slideshow Issue [RTL]

Tags: html, css

So, I recently started learning `HTML` and `CSS`, and I believe I've gotten to a point where I'm relatively good at it, and so I tried to make my own website, as practice.
Didn't have a problem with anything (except maybe mobile responsiveness but that's for a different question). Anyways, I wanted a sort of slideshow background with around 6 pictures and for it to switch every 6 seconds, smoothly.
A friend helped me with this, since it's way out of my league in terms of `@keyframes` (after reading it I found it understandable but I don't think I would've understood it on my own).
And so the website I'm designing is in Hebrew (RTL direction language) and so I did a `<html dir="rtl"` like any normal person would, but when trying out mobile responsiveness after just finding out about how difficult it could be to set up, I tested it and I saw the background glitching out. I tried many different ways to identify the problem and after hours and hours of attempts to look for the problem, I found out that the RTL in the html is the problem. However, considering it's a website that is RTL and already has elements in it that are positioned to RTL, it could ruin everything. So that's where I come to you. Is there any way to fix this problem? Make it RTL? I tried adding direction to several of the `CSS` elements but nothing worked.

```
/* CSS codes */
   /* this is there to show no fading animation when you load the page for the first time */
.background-start{
    background-image: url(slideshow/slideshow1.jpg);
    position: fixed;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
}

.slideshow,
.slideshow:after {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0; 
}

.slideshow li span { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { 
    background-image: url(slideshow/slideshow1.jpg);
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(2) span { 
    background-image: url(slideshow/slideshow2.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(3) span { 
    background-image: url(slideshow/slideshow3.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s; 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(4) span { 
    background-image: url(slideshow/slideshow4.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s; 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(5) span { 
    background-image: url(slideshow/slideshow5.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s; 
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(6) span { 
    background-image: url(slideshow/slideshow6.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s; 
}

/* Animation for the slideshow images */
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation { 
    0% { opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
         animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}

.image_container
{
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```
<!-- HTML codes -->

<div class="image_container">
                    <div id="background-preload" class="background-start"></div>
                    <script>$('#background-preload').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');</script>

                    <ul class="slideshow">
                        <li><span></span></li>
                        <li><span></span></li>
                        <li><span></span></li>
                        <li><span></span></li>
                        <li><span></span></li>
                        <li><span></span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Apologies if it's not enough code, I just figure that posting the entire HTML and CSS document would be useless as it's very long and has nothing to do with this.

Thanks!